# Redash python - conditional result

Tags: python, redash

I badly need help. I've been searching codes around but couldn't find any.

in redash, using Python, I can get the query result by using

> get query result

the sample result would be:

| WEEK_OFF | EMAIL | STATS |

| --- | --- | --- |

| 2023-03-06 | email1@gmail.com | 97.54 |

| 2023-03-06 | email2@gmail.com | 33.57 |

| 2023-03-06 | email3@gmail.com | 98.99 |

| 2023-03-13 | email1@gmail.com | 23.00 |

| 2023-03-13 | email2@gmail.com | 77.54 |

| 2023-03-13 | email3@gmail.com | 88.23 |

What I would like to do is
only modify res such that it only contains rows with email3@gmail.com. I know I can do this at the query level; however, I have a specific use case where I had to do it in Python.